# use SmbFileInputStream to read data in utf-8 encoding

Tags: java, file, utf-8, character-encoding, fileinputstream

i have a file which has the following string:

```
Vol conforme à la réglementation
```

However, when i read the file using SmbFileInputStream i get:

```
Vol conforme � la r�glementation
```

Could you please let me know the best way to read this file so that I get the String as I have in the original file. I am converting it to utf-8, which I am not sure is the correct way. Here is the current code that I am using:

```
SmbFileInputStream smbFileInputStream = new SmbFileInputStream(fileURL);
BufferedReader bufferedFileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(smbFileInputStream, "UTF-8"));
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while ((line = bufferedFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } finally {
        bufferedFileReader.close();
    }
```

Comment: your code is correct for reading a file with utf-8 encoding.  the real question is what the _actual_ encoding of the file is.

Comment: `InputStreamReader(smbFileInputStream, "UTF-8")` should decode a UTF-8 encoded file. Due to way it's been corrupted, I suspect the file is not UTF-8 encoded or you're printing using the wrong encoding. How are you checking the output?

Comment: thats a good point... the first line in the file says:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>

Comment: However, I just tried using UTF-16, and it just returns me all garbage characters.. so, i tried to convert that result into a UTF-8 and it returns all question marks.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I am debugging and inspecting the element. Also, sending the same to my UI, where it shows the same.

Comment: Based on the output, I suspect the file is `iso-8859-1` encoded. You should be able to verify with a good text editor

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack thanks. I just checked using notepad. It shows "ANSI" encoded. So, should I read it with "ANSI" instead of "UTF-8" ?

Comment: "ANSI" just means the user's 8bit codepage. Use `iso-8859-1` or `cp1252` in Java, which are the character sets for Western Europe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is not UTF-8 encoded. Based on the output of the baked string, it's probably `ISO-8859-1` encoded or Windows `cp1252` encoded, or even `ISO-8859-15`.

You should pass these encodings instead. It won't be quickly obvious to know which one of these encoding to use until your data contains a byte which maps to the wrong character.

The Euro symbol is a good test. It doesn't exist in `ISO-8859-1` and is in different map positions in `cp1252` and `ISO-8859-15`.

Notepad++ is an awesome tool for quickly checking files with different decodings.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! ISO-8859-1 worked for me. I will do some regression testing as you suggested.